# Consulta de tablas muy grandes MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas muy grandes, de 8 gigas y a diario siguen creciendo.

Tengo algunas consultas donde hago, promedios, máximos, mínimos, desviación estándar y se cuelga un poco. Cuál sería el mejor método para este caso, realmente soy nuevo en estoy y solo en mi cabeza paso en dividir la tabla por secciones en otras sub secciones ya que los datos se llenan con un numeral y agrupar los 01 con 01, 02 con 02 .... y crear tablas para cada numeral.

Comment: Sería bueno saber qué estructura tienen tus tablas de trabajo pues podría ser que no esté bien definidos los índices necesarios o incluso el tipo de campo no es el óptimo.

Answer (score 1):

Pues algunas cosillas que se me ocurren sin todavía conocer detalles acerca de tu proyecto y cómo consumes dicha información, hasta que actualices tu pregunta con más información.

### Considera guardar los resultados en otra tabla

Cuando nos enfrentamos a problemas de rendimiento y escalabilidad la normalización de bases de datos pierde fuerza, olvídate de las reglas.

No soy experto en mysql, pero la solución que he visto en muchos sistemas es crear una nueva tabla para resultados parciales de otra, donde solo tiene dos campos, uno que indica la estadística (un varchar para el nombre) y otro con su valor. Esta tabla la actualizas o bien en inserción (quizás te conviene una vista entonces) o bien tras alguna petición. Es especialmente útil si tienes pocas inserciones, dado que puedes recalcular todo solo durante inserción y te quedas con campos precalculados para todas las lecturas que quieras de forma inmediata. Si tienes menos lecturas que escrituras, entonces esto solo empeora la situación

### Precalcular lo que necesitas de forma incremental

Puedes realizar procedimientos para esas estadísticas que sean matemáticamente incrementables (teniendo los resultados en otra tabla o vista). Por ejemplo, añadir un nuevo dato no hace que tu media calculada sea inservible, puedes simplemente actualizarla con el nuevo dato. Si a una media de una serie de datos le quieres añadir un `nuevoValor`, siendo X la nueva cantidad de datos, la fórmula es `(X-1)/X * antiguaMedia + (1/X) * nuevoValor`

Por ej para `2, 2, 4, 4` la media es 3. Si añadimos 5 la media es 3,4. Bien, no hace falta sumar todos los valores, siguiendo la fórmula:

`4/5 * 3 + (1/5) * 5 = 3,4`

Cada estadística probablemente tenga su versión incremental. Algunas como la mediana puede que se compliquen.

### Cachear resultados

Si es un sistema de información que van a consumir distintos usuarios, considera no brindar información en tiempo real si no es crítico. Esto es, cuando atiendas una petición, si ha transcurrido el suficiente tiempo desde la última vez que se solicitó, recalcula, guarda el resultado y siempre brinda el mismo directamente en sucesivas peticiones hasta que haya pasado un mínimo de tiempo.

### Escuchar en inserciones

8 GB de datos son realmente muchos datos. Quizás necesites una solución que te aporte mejor rendimiento si no dispones de suficientes recursos hardware. En sistemas que admitan una conexión en tiempo real, quizás te interese más monitorizar las nuevas inserciones y recalcular como te digo en la 2º opción directamente en el sistema consumidor (cliente).

Intenta brindar más detalles sobre tu proyecto y quizás podamos brindarte más ayuda específica.